# Which is preferred for typecasting to a String in JavaScript? String() or template literal?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have some variable that is probably a number.

Is it preferred to use `String()` or use a template literal to convert this variable to a string?

```
const n = 3.14;

let strN = String(n);

// OR

strN = `${n}`;
```

or does it not make any difference other than the obvious readability issues?

Comment: They behave the same in all cases[\*](/questions/50109936 "except when there’s a different String in scope, which is about as relevant as it is for undefined, i.e. not at all"). `String()` would make your intentions much clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: A little less intuitive, but concatenating `""` to anything makes it a string (i.e. `let strN  = n + "";`)

Comment: It's a matter of *opinion*

Answer (score 0):

[airbnb's styleguide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) suggests `String(n)`.

```
// => this.reviewScore = 9;
// good
const totalScore = String(this.reviewScore);
```

[airbnb Coercion: strings](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#coercion--strings)

[You Don't Know JS - Types & Grammar: Coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md)